# C# app - running FFMpeg from the command line is not working

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I'm trying to run FFMpeg from the Command Line in C#. Previously I was running it from "CMD.exe" and it was working, but that requires a local installation of ffmpeg with configuring my System environmental variables. So I wanted to run it directly from "ffmpeg.exe". I'm using the following code (all the paths are correct), and nothing happens:

```
string programToRun = "C:\\Users\\dkahn\\Documents\\PlaybackTool\\PlaybackTool\\Desktop\\Source\\Player\\Player\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe";

string directoryName = "C:\\Users\\dkahn\\Documents\\PlaybackTool\\PlaybackTool\\Desktop\\Source\\Player\\test\\test1-1.mp4";

string command = "@ffmpeg -i test1-1.mp4 -r 1  -s 180x101 test1-1\\output_%04d.png";

Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = programToRun;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = directoryName;
cmd.Start();
 cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);
cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
cmd.StandardInput.Close();
cmd.WaitForExit();
```

Does anybody have any insight?

Comment: Is `@ffmpeg` part of the arguments for `ffmpeg.exe`?

Comment: Maybe not, that was when I was running it from the command line (cmd.exe). But I just tried removing that and it's still not working.

Comment: Try setting the `cmd.StartInfo.Arguments` to `-i test1-1.mp4 -r 1  -s 180x101 test1-1\\output_%04d.png` and remove the lines where using the `StandardInput`.

Comment: This is what I got, it still doesn't work now..........

`cmd.StartInfo.FileName = programToRun;
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i test1-1.mp4 -r 1 -s 180x101 test1-1\\output_%04d.png";
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

                cmd.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = directoryName;

                cmd.Start();

                cmd.WaitForExit();`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved this issue.

```
           var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ffmpeg.exe");
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = path + "\\";

            startInfo.Arguments = "-ss " + _startTime + " -i " + info.FullName + " -t " + _duration + " -map 0 -c copy -c:a copy " + "sample" + GetExtension(info);//-acodec

            var processn = Process.Start(startInfo);
            processn.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            processn.WaitForExit();
```

where path is your directory and info is your file to process.